# Appcelerator - Javascript - losing the reference

Tags: javascript, widget, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I have the following code on my app to add widgets:

```
while(i < rc_length) {
    console.log(i);
    mooncards[i] = Alloy.createWidget("moonCards");
    mooncards[i].on('close',function(){
        $.dashboard_scroll.remove(mooncards[i].getView());
    });
    $.dashboard_scroll.add(mooncards[i].getView());
    i++;
}
```

So I can add `mooncards` on my `scrollview` and add a function to be triggered inside the widget to remove itself.

That was the idea, but unfortunately the only widget removed is the last one. Clearly the reference `remove(mooncards[i])` is lost while adding new widgets.

I'm still learning about Javascript, so I don't what I'm doing wrong here.

**How can I add a lot of widgets and remove each one specifically, without losing the reference?**

Please, let me know If I need to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a classic javascript binding issue.

I would try changing:

```
 $.dashboard_scroll.remove(mooncards[i].getView());
```

to

```
 $.dashboard_scroll.remove(this.getView());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
mooncards[i].on('close',function(){
    $.dashboard_scroll.remove(this.getView());
}.bind(mooncards[i]));
```

`bind` will replace `this` in your function with the first parameter that you give to it. Consider this example:

```
x = function() { console.log(this); }

// outputs the window context if running in browser
// because the value of 'this' is the context where
// where the function was executed
x(); 


// outputs a String object, 'hello' because the value of
// this has now been bound to the string 'hello'
x.bind('hello')();
```

If your users are in IE8 and below, you will need to use the polyfill provided in the link above.